# Is there a way to calculate the pixel length by marking two points on an image using android studio?

Tags: android, image, pixel, points, markers

I am working on a project which requires to get the pixel length between two points on an image. I am doing this using android studio. The pixel length must not change when zooming. How can I achieve this using android studio? Thanks in advance!

Comment: its possible,how do you want to mark the points by single tap, double tap or how??

Comment: First, the user needs to select a point by dragging a marker on the image. After that, he should be able to get the coordinates by tapping on the screen (Single tap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement the GestureDetector.onListener interface inyour activity or fragment.

Inside onDown function , you  will receive an MotionEvent object.

you can get y coorfinate of the tapped poiny by :
motioneventObj.getX() and y coordiante as getY().

assign these values to variables to be used in your program further when the next time onDown callback is called.

How to implenet he interface.. you wil find out here :

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector